# Proving $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^p\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathcal{P}^p$: Why take the derivative?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

I'm very confused with that...Why derivative?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The aim is to show that if the original sum is 0 then the only way that can happen is if all of the $c_i$ values are 0. Then the original polynomials must be linearly independent. Taking derivatives and putting $x = 0$ achieves that. There are other ways to do it too.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward answer is: Because it leads you to what you want. If you need to get a nail into the wand, you use a hammer. If your nose is running from cold, you use a handkerchief. If you want to make tea, you use a water heater or a kettle on a stove to boil water.

All of those things are tools to help you/allow you to do certain things. Somebody invented them, and in our lives we get shown how to use them and when to apply them. By use we learn what works and what doesn't. Using a handkerchief to put a nail into the wall is not likely to succeed.

In your problem, you want to know about the coefficients in the equation:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb R: c_0+c_1x+\ldots+c_px^p=0. \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$

The $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ is missing from the solution, which can be irritating, as obviusly such an equation can be true for $c_i \neq 0$ for **some** $x$, like $x^2-3x+2=0$ is true for $x=1$ and $x=2$ (but not for other values).

So we assume that the function $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+\ldots+c_px^p$ is identical to the function $g(x)=0$ (which is another way of saying \eqref{eq1}.

Putting certain values, like $x=0$, into the definition of $f(x)$ is a way of getting information about the coefficients. That may or may not be obvious you to. The solution shows that it is helpful, you get $c_0=0$ from doing that.

Calculating the derivative $f'(x)$ and comparing it with the $g'(x)$ (which are equal functions, as $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal functions) is a way of getting more information about the coefficients (in this case that $c_1=0$). **This is a helpful step towards your goal to show that eventually all $c_i$ must be $0$**.

If you've never seen a hammer before, you would be amazed at what it can do, compared to trying to put a nail into a wand with your bare hands. Somebody with knowledge about physics had the idea that using a heavy object with a way to accellerate it on a short path can create a much higher force than you can with your bare hand. They likely didn't come up with it out of thin air, but they may have tried things and looked what works and what doesn't and realize that the object being heavy had something to do with it.

The same thing is true for this math problem. Somebody with math knowledge at some point tried what would happen if they differentiated an idenity like \eqref{eq1} and they found that it gave them useful information. So this technique became a useful math tool, like the hammer became a useful tool doing small scale construction work.

Like learning what tools help you in everyday life, you learn how to use math tools as well. They make things easier or allow you to do things at all in the first place.

For example, it is possible to prove the statement of the problem without using derivatives. You would have to put in more values into \eqref{eq1} besides $x=0$, usually one uses $x=1, 2,\ldots p$. Then you get a linear system of equations for the $c_i$, which you can prove has a unique solution. It's easy to see that $c_0=c_1=\ldots=c_p=0$ is a solution, so it must be the only one.

But proving that the solution is unique is not that simple. By using the above differentiating technique, you avoided a lot of other work. It made the solution simpler, like a good tool does.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is linearly independent then an *equation of the form* $c_0+c_1x+ c_2 x^2+\ldots+c_p x^p=0$ shall have a unique solution for the parameters $\{c_0,...,c_p\}$.

By substituting $x=0$, we determine that $c_0$ does have a unique solution; $c_0=0$.

**But what of the rest?**  How might we inspect $c_1$?

Taking the derivative gives you *another* equation of that form.$$c_1+2c_2x+\ldots+pc_p x^{p-1}+0x^p = 0$$

If $B$ is linearly independent, then *this* equation shall *also* have a unique solution for the remaining parameters.

And so we likewise determine that $c_1$ does too have a unique solution, by the same method.

By iteration of this process, we find there *is* a unique solution for all the parameters; they are all $0$.